# Formatting double to string with ostringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream, number-formatting

I want to convert double to string, rounding to 2 decimal digits after point. I want 1.009 to be presented as "1.01", and 1.0 as "1". This is what I've tried:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << std::noshowpoint  << 1.0;
```

It outputs "1.00", even though I never set width and even specified `std::noshowpoint`. How to achieve the desired representation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best solution:

```
inline double twodec(double n) { return floor(n * 100 + 0.5) / 100; }

oss << twodec(1.0) << ' ' << twodec(1.009);
```

Discussion

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/ (italics mine)

> When floatfield is set to fixed, float values are written using fixed-point notation, which means the value is represented with *exactly as many digits in the fraction part as specified by the precision field* and with no exponent part.

So, "fixed" isn't going to work.

That said, the only ways I can think of to do what you want are:

- round the number first to the desired precision (i.e. `floor(n * 100 + 0.5) / 100`) first, then use the default presentation (i.e. don't specify fixed or scientific or precision - if `fixed` or `scientific` are in effect, first clear them with `std::cout.unsetf(std::ios::floatfield)`).
- dynamically setting the precision based on the maximum total number of numeric digits you want to see, before and after the point (which is what the precision specifies); to do that, you could work out how many digits the part before the decimal point takes (using log base 10 perhaps) and add 2
- streaming the result to a `ostringstream`, then removing trailing 0s and any '.' (pretty hideous).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that implication of `setprecision`.  Pity that such an easy task can't be solved by standard library without additional coding...

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: agreed, it's hideous :-(.  I hope someone has a better answer....

Answer (score 1):

This is my final solution based on Tony's answer:

```
template <typename T>
std::string stringForNumber( T f, int precision /* = 0 */, bool fixedWidth /*= false*/ )
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss.setf(std::ios_base::fixed);
    if (precision > 0)
        ss << std::setprecision(precision);

    ss << f;
    std::string str(ss.str());
    if (!fixedWidth) // Removing trailing 0
    {
        const auto pointLocation = str.find_first_of(".,");
        if (pointLocation != std::string::npos)
        {
            const auto lastZeroPos = str.find_last_of('0');
            const auto lastNotZeroPos = str.find_last_not_of('0');
            if (lastNotZeroPos == pointLocation) // Integer number
                str.erase(pointLocation);
            else if (lastZeroPos != std::string::npos && lastNotZeroPos != std::string::npos && pointLocation < lastZeroPos && lastNotZeroPos < lastZeroPos)
            {
                str.erase(lastNotZeroPos+1);
            }
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```